# Submitting an array of datetime_selects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 3.2.5, I can't seem to figure out how to collect many `datetime_select` results inside an inner array in `params`

For example, if I have this

```
<input type="text" name="poll[options][]">
<input type="text" name="poll[options][]">
```

Then params will contain `params[:poll][:options]` which is an array of all of the `options` fields.

Here's my `datetime_select`:

```
datetime_select "scheduler", "options", {
  add_month_numbers: true, 
  start_year: Date.today.year, 
  default: DateTime.now + 1.day, 
  datetime_separator: "<span>at</span>", 
  time_separator: "<span>:</span>", 
  leading_zeros: true
}
```

I want to repeat the `datetime_select` many times in the form.

The model/field parameters do not seem to allow finagling anything like `"scheduler[]"` or `"options[]"` in order to collect an array of `datetime_select` results.

How can I do this so that many datetime objects appear inside an array located at `params[:scheduler][:options]`?

### Update

Here is how I am currently hacking it:

```
datetime_select_tags = datetime_select "scheduler_selects", "", add_month_numbers:true, start_year:Date.today.year, default:DateTime.now + 1.day, datetime_separator:"<span>at</span>", time_separator:"<span>:</span>", leading_zeros:true
datetime_select_tags.gsub! 'name="scheduler_selects', 'name="scheduler[options][]'
```

This produces tags like

```
<select id="scheduler_selects__1i" name="scheduler[options][][(1i)]">
```

so `params` correctly contains

```
"scheduler" => { 
  "options" => [
    {"(1i)"=>"2012", "(2i)"=>"6", "(3i)"=>"13", "(4i)"=>"15", "(5i)"=>"24"}, 
    {"(1i)"=>"2012", "(2i)"=>"6", "(3i)"=>"13", "(4i)"=>"15", "(5i)"=>"24"}
  ],
},
```

I will probably try to wrap this in a helper in order to also produce unique HTML id attributes. Really hoping this is not the long-term solution, though.

Comment: Have you tried `datetime_select "scheduler", "options[]"`?

Comment: @chowlett Yes, that produces, in part `<select name="scheduler[options[](1i)]">`. Rails chokes on these name attributes and the `datetime_select`s will overwrite each other (i.e. I get just one back even if I list many on the page).

Answer (score 0):

Using trial and error, I found this to work:

```
<%= form_tag :things do %>
<%= datetime_select("dates[a]", "b" ) %>
<%= datetime_select("dates[c]", "d" ) %>
<%= submit_tag 'save' %>
<% end %>
```

This gives you hashes like `params[:dates]["a"]` and `params[:dates]["b"]`.  I couldn't get the inner index to work with symbols and I'm not sure how to make those 1i, 2i,... suffixes go away.

Comment: The `(1i)` suffixes are for re-building a DateTime object using multi-parameter assignment. Your solution got me closer. What this answer gets is a single hash of `b(1i)`, `d(1i)`, `b(2i)` attributes, which I guess is splittable....